# Regular expression to separate letters and number in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a Java program to separate letters and numbers. 
 For instance:

```
String input = "W10I34R4";

String[] output = {"W, "10, "I", "34", "R", "4"};
```

I believe I can do this with a regular expression, and have tried the following, though it doesn't seem to work:

```
Matcher.compile("[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]")
```

Any input would be helpful !

Comment: I believe you're missing a trailing `+` on that regular expression after `[0-9]`.

Comment: Question: if more than one letter is adjacent in the I out do you want each letter in a separate index of `output` or should all adjacent letters be in a single `output` index?

Answer (score 2):

Try this `"[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]+"` I assume you want letters separate